# How to check validation between two dates in datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using datepicker to get date, I need to do validation like if start date is greater than end date then need to display an error

I have tried with below code, but it dint work

```
    $('body').on('focus', ".datepicker", function () {
        $(this).datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: '<?php echo date_format_datepicker(); ?>',
            language: '<?php _trans('cldr'); ?>',
            weekStart: '<?php echo get_setting('first_day_of_week'); ?>',
            todayBtn: "linked"
        });

        var sDate;
        $("#product_start").datepicker().on('changeDate',function (ev) {
            sDate = $(this).val();
        });


        $("#product_end").datepicker().on('changeDate',function (ev) {
        var edate = $(this).val();
            if (sDate > edate) {
                // $('#edate').datepicker("setDate", sdate);
                $('#date_error').append("Date should lesser than start date")
            }

    });
```

HTML code

```
//Start date 
<input name="product_start" id="product_start" class="form-control input-sm datepicker">

//end date
<input name="product_end" id="product_start" class="form-control input-sm datepicker">
```

It prints prints error multiple times if start date greater than end date ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

1. You are using same id for 2 datepickers, which you shouldn't.
2. Multiple lines are printed because

   a. The condition is mostly `false`. Dates should not be compared as `strings`. Convert them to date objects and validate.

   b. You are just appending the text. Old messages will not be cleared and gets stacked. Replace the whole content every time or have a default error message and show/hide the `div` based on validation.

```js
$('.datepicker').each(function (){
    $(this).datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        todayBtn: "linked"
    });
});
var sDate,eDate;
$("#product_start").datepicker().on('changeDate',function(e){
    sDate = new Date($(this).datepicker('getUTCDate'));
    checkDate();
});

$("#product_end").datepicker().on('changeDate',function(date){
    eDate = new Date($(this).datepicker('getUTCDate'));
    checkDate();
});

function checkDate()
{
    if(sDate && eDate && (eDate<sDate))
    {
        $('#error').text("Date should lesser than start date");
    }
    else
    {
        $('#error').text("");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input name="product_start" id="product_start" class="form-control input-sm datepicker">
<input name="product_end" id="product_end" class="form-control input-sm datepicker">
<div id="error"></div>
```

Comment: Also make sure to store the UTC Dates if storing in the server or local date with timezone.

Comment: Hi Vignesh how  to change date format to  like this format 01-jul-2018

Comment: Change the format in the options while initializing the picker.